# The import org.apache.commons.httpclient can not be resolved

Tags: java, import, httpclient

I have downloaded the library
added the library 
refreshed the project
imported the library to project

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams;
```

However i still get the error

`The import org.apache.commons.httpclient can not be resolved`

can you please tell what is the problem with it?

Comment: How do you add the classpath of these libraries into your project? Do you using maven?

Comment: right click on the project > Build path > Configure build path >  libraries > add external jar